# Different no of columns in partitionBy output file csvs

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to `pyspark`, and an trying to write a `dataframe` to `csv` by using `partitionBy` on a particular column. The column has values from 0-1030. While the first few files are created correctly with the correct no of columns and the `partitionBy` column is dropped.

However some of the files are created along with the `partitionBy` column in the csv file  + another column that I drop before i write the `dataframe`.

Can someone help on this

```
Data.coalesce(1).write.mode(“overwrite”).partitionBy(“col”).csv(path)
```